# Rewrite rule to strip part of a url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How you you write a Rewrite rule in .htaccess to redirect all urls with the word test and (any strings after it)

e.g. /test/spiderman?id=something or /test/spiderman

To the same url with the test part removed

e.g. /spiderman?id=something

ps

A simple request to

/test/

would not match because there are no strings after the word /test/

Comment: The folder `/test` cab be in other level in the directory structure? For example `http://example.com/test/` or `http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/test/`.

Comment: the folder test only occurs at the first level. e.g. http://example.com/test/